# ReactJs: not wait Axios result in componentdidmount()

Tags: reactjs

i want to set string within my state after axios success in componentDidMount() and use this state on this page, but when i call axios flow is not wait for axios success and i am getting blank status.

please find the below code:

```
componentWillMount() {

    axios.get(config.Rype_services_url + "Backtest/Subscription/" + this.props.authUser.uid)
            .then(function (response) {
                debugger
                if (response.data == "NotAllow") {
                    errMsg= "Max BackTest Count."
                }
                else {
                    errMsg= ""
                }

                this.setState({
                    CheckSubscription:errMsg;
                })

            }).catch(function (e) {
        });
}
```

---

```
 '<div className="errorMessage" style={{ position: 'fixed', height: '0%', top: '50%', left: '30%', width: '62%', zIndex:'10' }}>{this.state.Error != "" ? <p style={{ background: '#ff0000', color: '#fff', padding: '15px 0px', }}>{this.state.Error}</p>: ""}</div>'
```

#### Now my main concern is that

my service called properly and get appropriate output but componentDidMount() is not wait for axios output and always i found blank value in my state.

I want to sync the axios, wait for output and then componentDidMount() function should be end.

Comment: Change the callback function to an arrow function and `this` will refer to what you expect. `.then((response) => { ... })`

Comment: this axios is called in parent component and the values of **CheckSubscription** use to chilled component as **this.props.CheckSubscription**. 
Still the this.props.CheckSubscription values is blank and after response method called.

Comment: As we know that first call componentWillMount() of parent component then call componentWillMount() of chilled component. i want to set my property in **CheckSubscription** property should be set on my parent component's componentWillMount() and then call the chilled component's componentWillMount() and used the property in chilled component.

Answer (score 0):

Your context does not seem to be bound to your callback function since you are not using an arrow function/bind.

Not binding your context will lead to `this.setState` being undefined. This can be solve in the following code using an arrow function :

```
componentWillMount() {
    axios.get(config.Rype_services_url + "Backtest/Subscription/" + this.props.authUser.uid)
        .then(response => {
            debugger
            this.setState({
                CheckSubscription: response.data == "NotAllow" ? "Max BackTest Count." : "" //Shorter syntax of your previous code
            })

        }).catch(e => {});
}
```

Pleas also keep in mind that you should not try to make lifecycle function asynchronous as it may produce unpredictable behavior from React.

Comment: this axios is called in parent component and the values of **CheckSubscription** use to chilled component as **this.props.CheckSubscription**. 
Still the this.props.CheckSubscription values is blank and after response method called.

Comment: As we know that first call componentWillMount() of parent component then call componentWillMount() of chilled component. i want to set my property in **CheckSubscription** property should be set on my parent component's componentWillMount() and then call the chilled component's componentWillMount() and used the property in chilled component.